# How do I scroll an HTML multiple-selection select box to the first selected option?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, html-select

I am trying to get an HTML multiple-selection `select` box to scroll to the first selected option, but I cannot find any way of doing so. Is there a way?

```
<select id=s multiple> 
<option value=0>One</option>
...

<option value=99 selected>Many</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below function that will look for the first selected element in your list, and will scroll the select box to it.

**Make sure you call the function when you already have the selections loaded, usually on `window.onload` event, but if you're populating the selections with ajax call, the function needs to be called respectively (once the selections are already in place)**

```js
// this is how you call the function, using the ID ("s") in your example:
window.onload = function(){
 scrollToSelected( "s" )
}

function scrollToSelected( select_id ) {
  var select = document.getElementById( select_id );
  var opts = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
  for ( var j = opts.length -1; j > 0; --j ) {
    if ( opts.item(j).selected == true ) {
      select.scrollTop = j * opts.item(j).offsetHeight;
      return;
    } 
  }
}
```

With the following line you can set the exact scroll position:

```js
select.scrollTop = j * opts.item(j).offsetHeight;
```

... the above will attempt to scroll until the selected  will be in the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice.

It seems that I cannot post code in a comment, so I will need to put this here. What seems to work is `height: 20px;` in the CSS for the `option` tag and the following Javascript:

```
 var select = document.getElementById(select_id);
    if (!select) console.error("no " + select_id);
    var opts = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
    var j = select.selectedIndex;
    if (j == -1) return;
    select.scrollTop = j * 20;
```

I'm getting `0` for the option's `offsetHeight` but hard coding a value as above seems to work.